# Java: algorithm to obtain all combinations of pairs of an array of strings not inverted

Tags: java

I have a string Array:

```
List<String> st=new ArrayList<String>();
st.add("Massachusetts institute"); 
st.add("of");
st.add("Technology");
```

I would like to implement an algorithm to obtain all combinations of pairs of an array of strings is not inverted, that I would get all these combinations:

```
-Massachusetts institute
-of
-Technology
-Massachusetts institute, of
-Massachusetts institute, Technology
-of, Technology
-Massachusetts institute, of, Technology
```

Naturally also strings of greater length, for example:

```
List<String> st=new ArrayList<String>();
st.add("Massachusetts institute"); 
st.add("of");
st.add("Technology");
st.add("MIT");
```

I should get:

```
-Massachusetts institute
-of
-Technology
-MIT
-Massachusetts institute, of
-Massachusetts institute, Technology
-Massachusetts institute, MIT
-of, Technology
-of, MIT
-Technology, MIT
-Massachusetts institute, of, Technology
-Massachusetts institute, of, MIT
-Massachusetts institute, Technology, MIT
-Massachusetts institute, of, Technology, MIT
```

Comment: Try using CombinatoricsLib to generate combinations of specific size. Should do the trick.
https://code.google.com/p/combinatoricslib/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without the formatting of whitespaces, the following is what I did:

```
// Your code
List<String> st=new ArrayList<String>();
st.add("Massachusetts institute "); 
st.add("of ");
st.add("Technology ");
st.add("MIT");
/* Added a few more to st for my own tests - see IDEONE link below */
//-------------------------------------------------------------------

/* Additional code */
Set<String> combs = new HashSet<String>(); // Set of matches default 16 spaces
/* The code should work even if the size goes above 16 - tried it in IDEONE */

int p = st.size(); // Get the endpoint

for(int i =0; i<p; i++){
     for(int j=i+1; j<p; j++) {
         combs.add(st.get(i) + st.get(j));
    }
}
Iterator g = combs.iterator();

while(g.hasNext()) {
    System.out.println(g.next());
}
}
/************************************************/
```

The demo is here - http://ideone.com/K92Xwi Also, after reading some relevant comments, Apache library for PermutationIterator, google code library for Combinatorics, etc. should also help you. But the code above doesn't use anything than main Java.